# HTML - Understanding href and the link and base tags

Tags: html, hyperlink, directory, radix

I often get confused with the href attribute, the link tag, and the base tag. I'm unsure how to properly link the CSS file so a file can be moved into a subfolder and still work (example later on) so I went ahead and found out how the href works when specifying a location.

For your knowledge, I'm working with my localhost, so I have the main `htdocs` folder and inside that, I have multiple folders, each for a project I'm working on. It ends up looking like this:

```
localhost/index.php (which redirects to localhost/home/index.php)
localhost/home/
localhost/zune/
localhost/school/
localhost/aeac/
```

And generally the layout of a folder will be something along these lines:

```
localhost/aeac/images/
localhost/aeac/stylesheets/
localhost/aeac/scripts/
```

Going on, let's say I have the file `localhost/aeac/test/index.html` and in it, I have 4 links for testing. I've found out that

```
<a href="/"> will link to "localhost/"
<a href="./"> will link to "localhost/aeac/test/" (the directory the file is in.)
<a href="../"> will link to "localhost/aeac/" (the directory above the file.)
<a href="about.html">will link to "localhost/aeac/test/about.html" (the directory the file is in.)
```

Now that I understand href's, I need to understand how to link CSS properly.

Imagine the site's directory looks like this:

```
localhost/aeac/
localhost/aeac/images/
localhost/aeac/stylesheets/
localhost/aeac/scripts/
```

and right in the `/aeac/` folder I have `index.html`. The file has a link tag that looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.css" />
```

So that works out well, main is basically the site's structure/theme and gets included in every file. The problem occurs when I have to make a subfolder. Now we have a `localhost/aeac/users/*username*/index.html`. The site still uses the main.css, but the link doesn't work anymore because there is no `stylesheets` folder inside there.

That's where I'm stuck, I imagine that I should be using the base tag to solve my problem but I'm still confused on how that would written. Also, I know I could just change the link tag for all the files in the users folder, but I'd like to know how to do it this way (if that's even possible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/aeac/stylesheets/main.css" />
```

This begins with `/`, so it will always traverse up from the root, not matter where your page is located (i.e. at `/aeac/index.html` or at `/aeac/users/foo/index.html`).  Now, if you have control over the tag in each copy of `index.html` (which you probably do), you could also navigate upwards with `..`, to `../../stylesheets/main.css`, but navigating from the root is probably simpler.

Answer (score 2):

with what you found out about href, just combine that knowledge about navigation with your final approach:

So if you have this:
localhost/aeac/
localhost/aeac/images/
localhost/aeac/stylesheets/
localhost/aeac/scripts/
localhost/aeac/users/

and you are in localhost/aeac/users/index.html
you just go one directory up (../ to get into aeac) and then navigate on:

../stylesheets/style.css

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can have an absolute path to the stylesheet using / as the base

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/aeac/stylesheets/main.css" />`

Answer (score 1):

You can use: 
/stylesheet/main.css

or ../../stylesheet/main.css

No matter what the "user" folder is named, ../.. will always go 2 folders back:

/aeac/users/user1/index.html
/aeac/users/user2/index.html

../../stylesheet will always get to /aeac/stylesheet